# R: How to interpolate a string variable into a vector

Tags: r, string, vector, interpolation

i am having trouble to use custom strings in a vector, like this:

```
myString = "bar"
anotherString = "foo"

foo <- c(myString = 1, anotherString = 2,)
foo
```

❌ Output:

```
myString anotherString
       1             2
```

❓ Desired result:

```
bar foo 
  1   2
```

How can I achieve to get this without hardcoding the string into the vector? I've tried `c(paste(myString) = 1)`. But this won't compile.

Comment: One option: `setNames(1, myString)`

Comment: Hi, were you able to get what you need with the link?